# Ruby .times .upto .downto, etc. Offsetting the printed value

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to offset the value that has been passed in the code block.

For example

C# - This will always print 5

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  i=5
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Ruby - This will print 5 for only 10 times.

```
10.times do |i|
  i = 5
  puts i
end
```

Is there a way to get |i| to get back to 5?

and another question. How can you make .times block skip(not increasing by 1 all the time)

Comment: Please don't say "return" when you mean "print". It's confusing. Thank you.

Comment: Both examples are nonsensical. Why would you want to specify doing something a certain number of times, and then *not* want to do it that many times? I can't help but think there's a better solution to whatever it is you're trying to do. Care to share a bit more?

Comment: @mu My question wasn't about manipulating a loop, it was about the predetermined number of times. It may be a case of for-loop mentality where an iterator would be better, but we cannot tell unless we're given more context.

Comment: @Mark Thomas It seem like using "while is a way to go" but as I see many programmer uses times, upto, downto, step for looping in Ruby. So I guess there's a way to manipulate to loop internally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't reset the counter of `times`, `upto` etc. from within the block.

You can use `redo` to restart the current iteration of the loop, which in this case will have a similar effect:

```
10.times do |i|
  i = 5
  puts i
  redo
end
```

This will print 5 forever (though take note, that the initial value of `i` will still be `0` at each iteration).

If you need more control than this, you need to use a `while` loop. Though I'd advice that in most cases where you think you need this, you actually don't and you're just approaching your problem from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'next' keyword to skip iterations based on certain criteria if need be.

```
10.times do |i|
  next if i < 5
  puts i
end
```

Also you may use the keyword 'redo' as described by sepp2k.

Answer (score -1):

This will print the value 5 ten times.

```
 i=5
 10.times{puts i}
```